# Address of a variable using pointer

Tags: c, pointers

Consider the following code in C

```
int x=100;
int*addr=&x;
```

I know that addr will store the address of x.A question that keeps popping in my mind is that the addr pointer will have its own address and that can again be accessed using ampersand operator and that too will be stored somewhere,so we have here infinite recursion on addresses so where does this end?

Comment: It doesn't end... you could have an `int**************************`. Also, unless you *create* a pointer, the address isn't stored anywhere.

Comment: You can write the address of a house on a piece of paper and put it in another house. Then you can write the address of that house on another piece of paper and put it in yet another house. You can then put the address of the third house on a third piece of paper and put it in a fourth house. _so we have here infinite recursion on addresses so where does this end?_

Comment: It ends when you stop adding `*` to a type. Think of it this way. All of the types like `int *`, `int **`, and so on are known at compile time. If there is an implementation-defined indirection limit, you will know about it at compile-time so it's not really infinite in the sense that a loop or recursive function call can be infinite.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The address of `addr` isn't "stored" anywhere explicitly, it just is. If you were to declare a second variable and use it to store that address, then sure it takes space:

```
int **addr2 = &addr;
```

You can think of the memory as a series of boxes. Assuming 4-byte `int` and pointers, and little-endian byte order, your scenario might look like:

```
+----------+--+--+--+--+
| Address  |Data bytes |
+----------+--+--+--+--+
|0x00000000|64|00|00|00|
+----------+--+--+--+--+
|0x00000004|00|00|00|00|
+----------+--+--+--+--+
```

The address is shown on the left, the bytes contained at that location on the right. You can see the value `100` stored in the first four bytes (100 decimal is 0x64 in hex). The second 4-byte location holds the value 0x00000000, which is the address of `x`. The address 0x00000004 is not stored anywhere.

Now if we add a second pointer, we'd use more memory:

```
+----------+--+--+--+--+
|0x00000008|04|00|00|00|
+----------+--+--+--+--+
```

That would be the memory used to represent the `addr2` pointer, and you can see that it contains the address of `addr`, i.e. 0x00000004.

Dereferencing `addr2` with the expression `*addr2` would yield the value at address 0x00000004, i.e. 0x00000000 with the type `int *`. De-referencing that once more yields the `int` at that address, i.e. 0x00000064.

Since this memory layout is chosen by the compiler, it "knows" the addresses involved, and can just substitute so that when code references `addr2`, it generates instructions that manipulate address 0x00000008, and so on. In real code this would probably all happen on the stack, but the principle is the same.

Final note: do heed [@Phil Perry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2433987/phil-perry)'s advice; the above simplifies and makes ocncrete a lot of things that are meant to be somewhat abstract. This is how it really does work on many current-day architectures, but many of the things mentioned are not guaranteed by C so you cannot really depend on them to always hold true. I meant the above as an illustration to (hopefully) make the concepts slighly less vague.

Comment: Thanx especialy for yours visuals.it helped.

Comment: You omitted an asterisk: `int** addr2=&addr`.

Comment: Just to add a **caution**: don't think of _pointers_ as some kind of _integer_. There's no guarantee that a pointer fits into a specific number of bytes, or that it's even a single number (think of the old Intel 808x segmented architecture). Be very careful about what kind of things you try to do with pointers!

Comment: @PhilPerry Good point, I edited in some words to that effect. I do think that `sizeof (T)` can be evaluated for every pointer type `T`, don't you?

Comment: sizeof and add/subtract elements from a pointer should always be defined, maybe difference between 2 pointers (of the same type, at least), too. I was just cautioning that programmers tend to think of pointers as just another kind of integer, and do improper things like cast them into a word int.

Answer (score 13):

If you store an address, naturally, you need some place to store it (i.e. *another* address), so you can continue this for as long as you wish. This ends precisely when you want it to end.

```
int         a = 1;
int       *pa = &a;
int     **ppa = &pa;
int   ***pppa = &ppa;
int ****ppppa = &pppa;
...
```

Here is a quick analogy: let's say you have a notebook with numbered pages and lines. Suppose you make a note on page 3, line 8, and then you want to reference that note from some other place. Perhaps you can write on page 7, line 20, a reference "see note on page 3, line 8". Now the reference has its own "address" - namely, page 7, line 20. You can reference it, too - on page 8, line 1, you could write "see note on page 7, line 20". You can continue this chain of referencing for as long as you wish.

Comment: Also consider you can't do `&&a`. Why is that? Because `&a` doesn't have an address until you store it somewhere.

Answer (score 7):

C implements what is called a *von Neumann machine*. You can compile C on other kinds of computers, if you can make the computer do what a von Neumann machine would do.

So, what is a von Neumann machine? **With apologies to the BBC, most people assume that programs in memory have strict and distinct notions of code and data, but actually -from a unified, von Neumann perspective- a program's memory space is more like a big ball of wibbly-wobbly, numbery-wumbery... *stuff*.** You can access and even alter it like data, or you can run it like code. But this latter isn't a good idea if you aren't certain that it's working code, which is one of the reasons people don't use assembly very often any more. Higher-level programming languages carefully organize the numbers into something that (ideally) works: they're not perfect at this, and C is, by design, less perfect at it than most. But they usually get the job done.

Now, what does this have to do with your question? **As you say, every variable has to have an address, and C has to know what these addresses are in order to use them.** The exact implementation details can vary from compiler to compiler, and sometimes on different settings within the compiler, but in some cases, the program doesn't even know the variable names anymore by the time it gets to the level of machine code. The addresses are all that's left, and they are what actually get used.

**These addresses are decided by the compiler. Ultimately, they become part of the code itself**. They're kept in areas that you shouldn't normally access, but can if you REALLY need to. Those areas are basically where the recursion stops.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have an infinite recursion. Each variable has its address and that's it. Now if you define a variable that is equal to the address of another variable than the address variable itself will be stored somewhere and will have an address. An address itself does not have an address **the variable** that stores it does.

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually, storage space is only allocated for the pointer when you store the address:

1) In your case: `int*addr=&x;`, `addr` will occupy `sizeof(int*)` bytes of memory. (But a compiler reserves the right not to store the pointer in memory: it might keep it in a CPU register).

2) `&x` doesn't explicitly allocate any storage.

3) `&&x`, `&&&x` etc. are not syntatically valid so you don't need to worry about potential recursion here.

The fact that `&&` used to be illegal syntax allowed C++11 use adopt this for *r-value references*.

Answer (score 2):

Of course the address pointer will have its own address, but unless you specifically access the address it holds it is not used so there is no recursion for this ...

Answer (score 2):

Lets look it this way. We have `limited` memory. Out if this whole memory, limited amount of memory is allocated for compilers to `STORE` their variables. U can declare as many variables as u wish BUT a time will come when u can't make more variables BECAUSE the `allocated memory` will run out space. So, as for your question, the answer is `NO`. there is no infinite recursion due to Limited Allocated Space to store variables.

Answer (score 2):

Pointers are like a house and its address in a locality. The house is real and its address is the way to locate the house. Assume there are two houses, X and ptr and I need to store the address (probably writing it in piece of paper) of one house, say X in another house say ptr. 
With this arrangement If i need to know the address of X i can look in ptr but what is there in X, i need to visit the house personally. But currently i am not at all intrested to know the address of ptr.

To get it furter

```
ptr and X are two houses.

//lets say &X is a sheet of paper containing the address of house X. I am going to keep this address in the house ptr. So the address of X is stored in ptr.

ptr = &X;

//Now what about ptr. Only if I need to know the address, I need to write the address in some paper and store it again in some other house. Else I am happy to know the house exits.
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends...

It depends on the compiler and level of optimization. There is a chance the compiler decide not to store your pointer "addr" in the primary memory but just keep its value in a register using it to locate x in the primary memory.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of good answers here already but let me add one more. I want to clarify a rather subtle point made by Bathsheba. You said:

> the addr pointer will have its own address and that can again be accessed using ampersand operator and that too will be stored somewhere

That sentence is wrong in a subtle way. Here is a rephrasing that is correct:

> If the ampersand operator is used on the storage location that contains the pointer value then that storage location will have its own address...

A pointer is a *value*. All values are stored *somewhere*. **But not all storage locations have addresses!** There are storage locations that do not have addresses -- they are called *registers* -- and a compiler is free to use a register for any storage location *provided that the address of that storage location is never taken*.

So when you say:

```
int x = 100;
int*addr = &x;
```

Then the storage location associated with variable `x` must have an address because its address is *taken*. But there is no requirement that the storage location associated with `addr` have an address *because its address is never taken*; therefore it could be *enregistered*. It is not *required* to be enregistered, but it could be.

Make sense?

Answer (score 2):

@unwind's answer is good, but there's one enormous caveat: the C language lets you create a pointer to just about anything, and that can get you in trouble.  Consider this tiny C program:

```
/*
 * show that a variable allocated on the heap sticks around, while a
 * variable allocated on the stack vanishes after its enclosing
 * function returns.  Holding a pointer to the latter can lead to 
 * unexpected results.
 */
#include <stdio.h>

int heapvar = 20;

int *get_heapvar_ptr() {
  return &heapvar;
}

int *get_stackvar_ptr() {
  int stackvar = 30;
  return &stackvar;
}

int main() {
  int *heap_ptr = get_heapvar_ptr();
  int *stack_ptr = get_stackvar_ptr();

  /* should print value = 20 */
  printf("heapvar address = %#x, heapvar value = %d\n", heap_ptr, *heap_ptr);
  /* you might expect this to print value = 30, but it (probably) doesn't */
  printf("stackvar address = %#x, stackvar value = %d\n", stack_ptr, *stack_ptr);
}
```

When run (at least in my environment), I get:

```
heapvar address = 0x22a8018, heapvar value = 20
stackvar address = 0x5d957fac, stackvar value = 0
```

Note that stackvar's "value" is now zero even though it had been set to 20.  This is because stack_ptr points to a place on the stack that has been overwritten by some other function.

To its credit, the compiler alerted me `warning: address of stack memory associated with local variable`, but the moral of the story is that pointer arithmetic in C is very powerful and correspondingly dangerous!